# Links to maven build commands in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, intellij-idea

A coworker of mine has IntelliJ.  She is able to create links to maven build commands that she uses often.  On Netbeans I have to right click on the pom file and type out my command.  From that same screen, Netbeans also provides caching of your previous commands so that you do not have to type them in again, just click on the little left or right arrow to scroll to the command you want to execute.

Is it possible to create maven build command links like how they are supported in IntelliJ?  The maven build command links are listed along the right hand side where they can easily be accessed without having to right click on the pom or on anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I just found a possible a shortcut.  You can actually save your maven build commands when you type it out after right clicking on the POM.  When you give the build command a name then it will show up when you right click on the POM.  This is not as good as IntelliJ's links but it does take me two steps closer.

I'll leave the question unanswered in case anyone knows a quicker shortcut that does not involve right clicking on the POM.

EDIT:  Your saved build commands are retrievable by right clicking on the your project and selecting Custom from the pop-up menu.  All your saved maven build commands are listed there.  Furthermore, Netbeans stores these custom maven builds in a file called nbactions.xml.  You can go into that file to edit them.  Below is an example

```
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-unit test, jacoco</actionName>
        <displayName>unit test, jacoco</displayName>
        <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>-DAPPLICATION=someApp</goal>
            <goal>-DanySystemProp=value</goal>
            <goal>-DENVIRONMENT=unit-test</goal>
            <goal>jacoco:report</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
```

Comment: if the command execution only involves a maven goal to run, the navigator window will list some maven goals to run when you select a maven project. However any configuration on top of goal selection requires a right-click and the Goals... dialog